# $U$-reflexive modules in Morita duality

Tags: modules

Let $_RU_S$ define a Morita duality between $R$ and $S.$ Exercise 25 in Lam,"*Lectures on Modules and Rings*," asks one to show that if $R$ is left-Artinian, then the $U$-reflexive $R$-modules are precisely the finitely generated ones (among other things). I believe this holds also if we replace $U$ by $R$ in the case that $R$ is quasi-Frobenius. Is it known for which rings $R$ the $U$-reflexives are precisely the finitely generated $R$-modules?